DIY ATX Desktop PSU turns off after using full load fast
I have built a desktop PSU with a fuse, output connector and a buck boost converter. The problem is that when I set the maximum power of the converter at once, the PSU turns off automatically. However, if I now switch on at 5V, for example, and then increase to 36V, the power supply unit does not switch off. The question now is, what can I do to prevent the power supply from switching off automatically without deactivating the safety chip in the power supply? No load was connected during testing.
The following are the values of the converter:
Input voltage: 6-36V
Output voltage: 0-36V
Output current: 0-6A
Output power: 120W
Bought: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005007309288430.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.58.72f61802ilPKoQ
Power supply:
+12V1 -> 12A

+12V1 -> 12A
+12V2 -> 12A
together 228W


What have I changed?
In some tutorials I had seen that you should use a resistor so that the power supply starts. i left that out because the power supply works the same way.
I connected all +12v1 cables to one and connected it to the converter. This passes the current to the connection via the fuse.


So you made an adjustable lab supply from an ATX PSU and are asking the same thing why it does not work well? Have you read all similar questions to find out if this is a duplicate, or explain why it isn't a duplicate?

‘Safety chip’! You mean the over current protection? You could try adding a large electrolytic capacitor on the output of the ATX psu. This might solve or exacerbate the issue. Or simply avoid startup with 36V output.

the biggest thing i have here is a 100uF 16V electrolytic capacitor. unfortunately it didn't work. I could of course just accept that, but I want to have a product that works properly :D
